# Не получается вывести нормально меню?

Tags: opencart

https://ilikesushi.in.ua/reviews
тут хедер неправильно выводится
 Главная Новости Отзывы Франчайзинг
Акции О нас Доставка и оплата Публичная офертаЭта часть
https://ilikesushi.in.ua/
здесь нормально выводится и на других страницах нормально, кроме этой https://ilikesushi.in.ua/reviews

как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Найдите и удалите указанный на скрине стиль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]